# Getting notes from a folder other than the default one in Outlook VBA

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2003

I'm currently getting notes from the default folder using the code:

```
Set myNote = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderNotes)
```

How can I get notes from a different folder?

Comment: Do you mean you cannot get the relevant folder? If so, this may help: http://www.outlookcode.com/d/code/getfolder.htm

Answer (score 1):

You have to walk the folder hierarchy, for example if your other Notes folder is one level below the Inbox, the code would be

```
Set myNote = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("My New Notes Folder Name")
```